# Treeview with in dropdown jquery

Tags: jquery

is there any jquery plug-in where treeview will be there with in dropdown. if so then please give me the url.

Answer (score 2):

ref. this, http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Comment: That is only a treeview. I can find numerous such controls, but this does not give me what I am looking for.